# Getting "Incorrect syntax near"-error with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, syntax-error, sqldatareader

I'm getting error and I don't know what's wrong with the code, so If anyone can help me I would be grateful.

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

and the highlighted line is

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Code:

```
cn.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ispiti WHERE poID=@poID, sgID=@sgID, npID=@npID";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poID", pr);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sgID", pr1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@npID", pr2);

SqlDataReader rdr;

try
{
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Well done!");
    }
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an error in your SQL statement. You should change

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ispiti WHERE poID=@poID, sgID=@sgID, npID=@npID";
```

to

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ispiti WHERE poID=@poID AND sgID=@sgID AND npID=@npID";
```

Comment: M8 it took 1 minute for you to solve my problem on which I'm working whole afternoon. I overlooked the SQL statement part, and searched for problem elsewhere :) Thank you very much, I'll give you correct answer in 12 minutes (site doesn't allow me to accept answer sooner).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use comma in [`WHERE` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx). You need to use logical operations like `AND` or `OR` like;

```
WHERE poID=@poID AND sgID=@sgID AND npID=@npID
```

This clause takes [*search condition*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx) after it and there is no syntax for comma.

By the way, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and readers automatically instead of calling `Dispose` or `Close` methods manually.

Also don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.